# Socket Programming in C# Is this considered polling?

Tags: c#, sockets

so I have been trying out socket programming in C# using code found online. When looking at this code from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-in-c-sharp/

```
public static void ExecuteServer() 
{ 
    // Establish the local endpoint  
    // for the socket. Dns.GetHostName 
    // returns the name of the host  
    // running the application. 
    IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName()); 
    IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[0]; 
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11111);   
    // Creation TCP/IP Socket using  
    // Socket Class Costructor 
    Socket listener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, 
                 SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);   
    try {           
        // Using Bind() method we associate a 
        // network address to the Server Socket 
        // All client that will connect to this  
        // Server Socket must know this network 
        // Address 
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);   
        // Using Listen() method we create  
        // the Client list that will want 
        // to connect to Server 
        listener.Listen(10);   
        while (true) {               
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting connection ... ");   
            // Suspend while waiting for 
            // incoming connection Using  
            // Accept() method the server  
            // will accept connection of client 
            Socket clientSocket = listener.Accept();   
            // Data buffer 
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024]; 
            string data = null;   
            while (true) {   
                int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);                   
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 
                                           0, numByte);                                              
                if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) 
                    break; 
            }   
            Console.WriteLine("Text received -> {0} ", data); 
            byte[] message = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Test Server");   
            // Send a message to Client  
            // using Send() method 
            clientSocket.Send(message);   
            // Close client Socket using the 
            // Close() method. After closing, 
            // we can use the closed Socket  
            // for a new Client Connection 
            clientSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both); 
            clientSocket.Close(); 
        } 
    }       
    catch (Exception e) { 
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString()); 
    } 
} 
} 
}
```

I was wondering if the portion

```
while (true) { 
                int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes); 
                data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numByte);                                   
                if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1) 
                    break; 
            }
```

is considered a polling method and also reason why we do not simply use

```
int numByte = clientSocket.Receive(bytes);
data = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, numByte);
```

I have tried the above and it seems to work just as fine. So is there a reason why we use a infinite while loop that depends on the text  to stop reading? I have found many sources which seems to use this method. Why is this so?

Comment: No, it's not polling. That's because `.Receive()` is a blocking call -- it won't return until there's actually some data. Polling would be continuously checking if there is any data. The change you propose will generally work fine on a local connection, where the assumption that you will receive exactly the same number of bytes sent in one call often holds. It will break down if you try it on a real network, though, because TCP/IP is a stream-based protocol, not a message-based protocol. You can get any number of bytes, and won't know if you're done unless you have an explicit length or EOF.

Comment: @JeroenMostert :why did you not add this as answer?

Comment: Hi please do correct me if I am wrong, I am very new to this. Does that mean assuming my server is made to echo back to my client. I can send multiple text from my client to server but it will not echo back until I send an <EOF> ?

Comment: @Kev The TCP is a stream, noticed the `SocketType.Stream` parameter? So you never know the start or and of a message unless you implement packet format with a header/data frame. In the case of text, you could split the data on a linefeed `\n`. But be aware that multiple lines can be stitched together or some might be split over multiple receives.